# Erro de tipo errado de parâmetro no mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\NOVO\admin\alterarfotos.php on line 16

```
$id_imagem = trim($_GET['id_imagem']);
   $dados = mysql_fetch_assoc(       mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imagens WHERE id_imagem = $id_imagem")      )or die(mysql_error());
```

> Notice: Undefined index: id_imagem in C:\xampp\htdocs\NOVO\admin\alterarfotos.php on line 15

Estou criando um simples álbum com MySQL & PHP porém estou tendo este erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), a função `mysql_fetch_assoc` espera que o **parâmetro passado seja do tipo** `resource`.

Porém você esta passando diretamente o retorno da função `mysql_query` como parâmetro, que, segundo [a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php) **retornará** `false` caso ocorra algum erro na execução da query.

Você deveria separar seu código da seguinte forma:

```
$id_imagem = trim($_GET['id_imagem']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imagens WHERE id_imagem = $id_imagem") or die(mysql_error());
$dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Obrigado ajudou bastante