# Erro ao buscar dados no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando `PHP` + `MYSQL` para fazer algumas consultas no meu banco de dados, essa página em `php` é a mesma que eu uso em outro host, lá funciona normal, porém, ao utilizar em um host diferente ela simplesmente não funciona.

### **O que eu alterei?**

Layout e conexões.

O erro em questão é

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given in /home/slim333/public_html/admin/consultar.php on line 134

Ativados:
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given in /home/slim333/public_html/admin/consultar.php on line 139

Não Ativados:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
boolean given in /home/slim333/public_html/admin/consultar.php on line 148
```

E nas linhas em que estão ocorrendo os erros estão as funções:

1. Linha 134 `$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`
2. Linha 139 `$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`
3. Linha 148 `while($lista2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){`

O Código atual está assim:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from n_emails WHERE ativo='s'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<font class='bebas' size='6' style='color:green'>Ativados: </font><font class='bebas' size='6' style='color:gray'>";
echo $data['total'];
echo "</font><br>";
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as totali from n_emails WHERE ativo='n'");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<font size='6' class='bebas' style='color:red'>Não Ativados: </font><font class='bebas' size='6' style='color:gray'>";
echo $data['totali'];
echo "</font>"
?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<br>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_emails order by -id");
while($lista2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$email = $lista2["email"];
$ativo = $lista2["ativo"];
if($ativo=="n"){
$ativo = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='red'>Não confirmado</font>";
}
else{
$ativo = "<font face='Arial' size='2' color='green'>Confirmado</font>";
}
?>
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, a pergunta é:

O erro realmente está nessas linhas? Se sim, como posso conseguir arruma-los ?

Preciso de uma luz.

@EDIT 20:38

> Não é duplicata [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32946/erro-de-tipo-errado-de-par%C3%A2metro-no-mysql-fetch-assoc) porque naquele caso, a pessoa não havia separado o código da forma correta, mas no meu caso, ele já está como a resposta para o problema do [Cauê Siqueira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32946/erro-de-tipo-errado-de-par%C3%A2metro-no-mysql-fetch-assoc).

Comment: É exatamente o mesmo problema, e a causa está explicada na resposta. O "estilo" do código não muda o erro. Se quiser, edite com seu código e ponha a parte da _query_, que podemos explicar melhor algo que você não tenha entendido. Mas pra resumir, é o mesmo erro, e a mesma causa. A conexão ou a _query_ tem erro, e está faltando o tratamento adequado antes de tentar usar o recurso Você está usando o _fetch_ num retorno que falhou.

Comment: @Bacco, desculpe meu conhecimento em PHP é quase igual a zero haha, editei a pergunta com o código inteiro (da parte que é referente ao erro).

Comment: O primeiro teste seria acrescentar isto no fim da linha: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from n_emails WHERE ativo='s'") or die( mysql_error() );` - e não precisa pedir desculpas, fazer mais de uma pergunta sobre o mesmo problema não é errado. A duplicata até ajuda as pessoas a acharem a mesma resposta pesquisando por termos diferentes. A idéia é que se der erro no $result, o PHP já vai parar e indicar o problema.

Comment: Mesma coisa nessa linha `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM n_emails order by -id") or die( mysql_error() );` - O "or die" vai fazer com que o PHP "morra" se a query não der certo, mostrando o erro na tela. (é o que está na resposta da pergunta indicada para o fechamento).

Comment: Faça o teste, e nos conte qual foi o resultado, estamos aqui pra ajudar. Se isso não resolver, podemos testar outras coisas.

Comment: @Bacco, muito obrigado mesmo pelo o que está fazendo ;) enfim, fiz os testes e pelo que parece o erro não está no code, retornou `No database selected`, ou seja, o problema é na conexão certo? Mas eu verifiquei o `config.php` e ele não tem nenhum erro, as outras partes do sistema não conseguem fazer consultas também, mas não retornam erros, apenas não mostram os resultados dizendo a mesma coisa `No database selected`

Comment: Tem duas soluções boas: ou vc coloca o nome da tabela assim: `SELECT talcoisa FROM nomedobanco.n_emails`, ou entao usa o `mysql_select_db( 'nomedobanco' );` antes do `mysql_query` - Tem como especificar na conexão também, mas geralmente se vc usar o `mysql_select_db` separado, ou o nome completo da nomedobanco.tabela , ajuda a usar a mesma conexão pra bancos diferentes

Comment: Exemplos: http://pastebin.com/Y1v9fMuN

Comment: Não confunda a conexão com seleção do DB. Na conexão vc especifica o servidor, esse servidor pode ter vários bancos, cada banco com suas tabelas. No seu caso, a conexão deu certo, faltou escolher o banco só.

Comment: Fiz isso, agora o erro foi `SELECT command denied to user 'slima248_user05'@'localhost' for table 'n_emails'`

Comment: Vi que o usuário parece não ter permissão, procurei pelo erro, achei uma query pra rodar direto no phpmyadmin, rodei e apareceu um erro: `Mysql: GRANT command denied to user 'slima248_user05'@'localhost' for table 'n_emails'`, procurei por esse erro também, achei uma resposta porém não me ajudou, estou quase cortando meus pulsos porque isso tá me irritando e muito haha

Comment: Ok, o importante é que você está cercando o problema verdadeiro, que é garantir que a coisa só continue depois de resolver esses passos. Nesse caso, faltou autorizar o 'slima248_user05'@'localhost' a acessar essa tabela. Lembre-se que quando usar o GRANT, você tem que dizer o nome do usuário e o HOST. (ou % para especificar qualquer host) - E no caso, vc tem que acessar como admin pra dar o GRANT pro usuário

Comment: É o problema é só esse, o único erro, autorizar o user a acessar a tabela, porem não tá dando, já tentei trocar o user, dar as permissões e nada, mesmo erro

Comment: Hehehe agora vc vai ter que se divertir um pouco com permissões (mas já venceu o problema da pergunta, ao menos). Sugeriria ver com o administrador do DB essa permissão (ou se o DB é seu, acessar como usuário root para fazer o grant)